# Custom Class Array sets value to two elements at once

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have some c# unity code that when I execute isn't working right. The code is below and should create an array of 5 score class objects that contain the score as an int and the name of the player as a string.

```
[SerializeField] Scores[] archeryScore = new Scores[5];

for (int i = 0; i < archeryScore.Length; i++)
            {
                archeryScore[i] = new Scores();
            }
```

This is the scores definition

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Scores
    {
        [SerializeField] private int score;
        [SerializeField] private string name;

        public int GetScore()
        {
            return score;
        }
        public string GetName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void SetScore(int newScore)
        {
            score = newScore;
        }
        public void SetName(string newName)
        {
            name = newName;
        }
    }
```

I'm using private variables and public methods to set the values but if I tried to set a score of 3 with the name Dave to element 0, it would set element 0 AND element 1 to a score of 3 with name Dave.

```
archeryScore[x].SetScore(score);
archeryScore[x].SetName(name);
```

*archeryScore is just an array of Score class objects* This is the code that sets the information and breakpoint testing shows that it's setting to the two elements at once.

The really confusing part of this is that if i set the array to be an integer array all of code works just fine.

[Here's a link to the full game manager file pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1jWdECkn)

TIA

Comment: Please re-read your question and make sure all details you though you've included are actually there. In particular "the code is below and should create an array of 5 score class objects" hints at some code that creates objects but none shown (note that question must contain [MCVE] of the debugging problem as textual representation of code *in the question itself*, links to something are nice but not considered part of the question)

Comment: Please also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347675/list-add-seems-to-be-duplicating-entries-whats-wrong which is likely duplicate, but without code in the question it is hard to say.

Comment: Are you sure `archeryScore[0]` and `archeryScore[1]`are *different* objects?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish in your SetHighScore method? Because I'm pretty sure it's not doing what you think its doing... I think you've used `break` when you meant to use `continue` and there's way too much code for what looks to be a shuffle?

Answer (score 0):

Deep down in `SetHighScore`

you are doing

```
archeryScore[x] = archeryScore[x - 1];
```

after this line these two indices hold a reference to the very same instance of `Scores` => You change the exact same object!

You should probably rather only copy over the according values.

I would use a dedicated method for that like e.g.

```
public class Scores
{
     ...

     public void CopyFrom(Scores other)
     {
         this.name = other.name;
         this.value = other.value;
     }
}
```

and then do

```
archeryScore[x].CopyFrom(archeryScore[x - 1]);
```

Note, however, that this probably still isn't doing what you want. Imagine running through that loop, you always copy the values of the last entry.

So the next time you iterate you again copy from the last entry -> But this last entry already copied the values from the entry before -> The all end up being one and the same values.

---

So in order to make your life **way** easier:

Why not simply use a `List<Scores>` instead?

```
[SerializeField] private List<Scores> acheryScore = new List<Scores>();
```

There you could simply always use `Insert` to insert a new HighScore at a certain index and then remove the very last entry of the list.

First of all I would use a proper constructor like

```
public class Scores
{
    ...

    public Scores(string name, int score)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

And then do

```
if (updateScore)
{
    archeryScore.Insert(scoreToUpdate, new Score(name, score));

    while(archeryScore.Count > 5)
    {
        archeryScore.RemoveAt(archeryScore.Count - 1);
    }
}
```